# Twitter media search

Tags: twitter, photos

Is it possible to search through Twitter's media for specific tags?

I know you can access the media via this url:

```
https://twitter.com/#!/therealpaddock/media/grid
```

Appending media/grid to the end of a user's ID, I was wondering if there is a way to search through all the twitter media photos via a tag???

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/user-streams

http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/

I have been searching through the API and googling, and I can't find anything out there that does this.

I have been looking at Twitpic's API but can't seem to find anywhere that lets you search and display images.

Answer (score 2):

Tag? I'm not sure you understand Twitter. A photo is simply attached to a tweet. A tweet may have a hashtag. If you want to search by hashtags, simply use the normal tweet search, then filter the photos.

Not sure why you linked to Twitpic, as what you're looking for is the normal Twitter search. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the Twicsy API.
It allows you to search all Twitter pictures using a search term (which is what I think you mean by tag).

```
http://api.twicsy.com/search/foo
http://api.twicsy.com/search?q=foo
```

They also provide ways to filter results, by number of results and date. (Go to the API docs for more details).

Another solution would be to use the Twitter search API to make the query and parse out the images manually. This [blog post](http://blog.embed.ly/findpitcom-building-a-twitter-image-search-wi) explains how.